# How to enable HTTP Port on Existing Workflow Manager Node

Tags: sharepoint, workflow-foundation-4

We installed Microsoft Workflow Manager on our SharePoint farm. When we first added the WF node, we configured not to allow http. For testing, we want to how allow HTTP.

The command [update-WFHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj193262(v=azure.10).aspx) does not seem to have a parameter for -EnableHttpPort.

We can remove the node and add back but was hoping to be able to make the change via a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open **IIS Manager**.
2. Select **Workflow Management Site** in left pane.
3. Press **"Bindings"** button in right pane.
4. Add binding for HTTP protocol (port must be different from port for HTTPS).
5. Open **PowerShell** and execute cmdlet **Register-SPWorkflowService** with setting value of parameter "WorkflowHostUri" to new http binding.

Comment: This was perfect solution.